# Перенос на виртуальную машину Linux

Tags: linux

С помощью Acronis был создан резервный образ системы linux suse 11, после данный образ был развернут на виртуальной машине. Однако при загрузке вываливается ошибка, т.к. оборудование не соответствует тому которое было на основной машине. Каким образом можно переопределить все оборудование?

Comment: Какая ошибка-то? В линуксе обычно ничего не привязано к оборудованию

Comment: К сожалению не могу в настоящий момент прикрепить фото, но выбивает что отсутствует определенный винчестер

Comment: Скорее всего не винчестер, а корневой раздел диска, и для этого достаточно просто прописать правильный путь или UUID в файл /etc/fstab и переустановить загрузчик

Comment: А есть какая нибудь инструкция по данному вопросу?

Comment: Инструкций по восстановлению загрузчика в интернете навалом, а для ответа чего-то конкретного не хватает более подробной информации - помимо самого текста ошибки, ещё разметка диска, содержимое fstab и собственно используемый загрузчик (скорее всего grub2, но вдруг не он)